# Covariant return types and rvalues references

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, covariant-return-types

I aim to implement an operator on derived classes such that the return type should be of the derived class.

I was able to achieve it with the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base{
public:
  virtual Base&& operator+ (const Base &b)  = 0;
  virtual void Val() = 0;
};


class Derived : public Base{
public:
  Derived&& operator+ (const Base &b) override
  {
    Derived *res = new Derived;
    auto tmp = dynamic_cast<const Derived*>(&b);
    if(tmp) res->fVal = this->fVal+tmp->fVal;
    return std::move(*res);
  }
  
  void SetVal(double val){fVal = val;}
  void Val() override{std::cout<<"derived:"<<fVal<<std::endl;}
private:
  double fVal{0};
};

int main(){
  Derived a;
  a.SetVal(2);
  Derived b;
  b.SetVal(3);
  Base *baseptr = new Derived(a+b);
  baseptr->Val();
  Base &&d = a+b;
  d.Val();
  Derived e = dynamic_cast<Derived&>(d);
  e.Val();
  return 0;
}
```

I am not really confortable with using an rvalue-reference for the return type, so I would like to know if there is a simpler solution that I cannot see. Returning a copy of the derived type didn't work, as gcc states that the return type is not covariant.

EDIT: As @ofo has mentioned, I could achieve something quite similar returning a lvalue-reference. For now it is the option that suits me the best. However, it is still undesirable (to say the least) that there is a memory leak waiting to happen, I just need to not do anything with the result of `a+b;`

Comment: Perhaps the [CRTP (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) could be helpful?

Comment: `virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> operator+ (const Base &b) = 0;`

Comment: "I am not really confortable with using an rvalue-reference for the return type" And this is 100% justified. Don't do that. In fact, don't do any of this exercise if you can help it. The entire idea of `virtual Base (whatever) operator+ (const Base &b)` is broken, it is known to be broken from the very beginning, there is no fix. Just don't do that.

Comment: Why not return lvalue-reference?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am not able to modify that much the already existing class hierarchy in which I would like the operator. But it would work, yes!

Comment: @ofo you are absolutely right, I don't see how it could be worse than returning rvalue-reference. Thanks!

Comment: @orlandini One sneaky issue can be dangling reference to a temporary expression, but as long as you don't bind result of temporary to a non-const reference, this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @ofo I am actually more concerned with the fact that the caller is now responsible for deleting the returned variable, I mean, using
`Base *b = &(a+b);` would most likely result in a memory leak.

Comment: @Eljay I think that this is the way to go. I posted an answer based on that.

Comment: Glad to be of help, but please take **n. 'pronouns' m** comment under advisement.  Doing these kinds of binary operators with polymorphism is a bit of a combinatorial nightmare, and likely lead to a bit of hard-to-debug & hard-to-maintain misery.  (If it's quasi-polymorphism, such as using the polymorphism mechanism as a kind of pointer-to-implementation pattern, then that's less of a concern.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way of achieving this without returning a pointer, as suggested by @Eljay. Returning a reference could work but I see no way of ensuring that the caller will delete whatever needs to be deleted.

I thought of this (where `func` represents a scenario in which I would use the operator):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base{
public:
  virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> operator+(const Base &) = 0;
  virtual void SetVal(double) = 0;
  virtual void Val() = 0;
};


class Derived : public Base{
public:
  std::unique_ptr<Base> operator+(const Base &b) override
  {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> res = std::make_unique<Derived>();
    auto tmp = dynamic_cast<const Derived*>(&b);
    if(tmp) res->SetVal(this->fVal+tmp->fVal);
    else std::cout<<"now i deal with invalid type case"<<std::endl;
    return res;
  }
  
  void SetVal(double val) override{fVal = val;}
  void Val(){std::cout<<fVal<<std::endl;}
private:
  double fVal{0};
};

void func(Base &a, Base &b)
{
  auto res = a+b;
  res->Val();
}

int main(){
  Derived a;
  a.SetVal(2);
  Derived b;
  b.SetVal(3);
  auto d = a+b;
  d->Val();

  func(a,b);
  return 0;
}
```

I will leave this up for a while in case someone finds a better solution. Otherwise I will mark it as an answer.

Comment: You are not using `Base` in your `main` except when forced to by the return type of `+`. If you don't want to use pointers to `Base` in your main program, simply ditch the entire class, or at least remove `virtual operator +` from `Base`.  Have `+` in `Derived` accept and return `Derived`, no dynamic cast, no virtual, no pointers.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. In the real code there are several derived types. I am interested in scenarios such as the function `func`, in which I dont know which are the exact types of the parameters. If there is no `operator+` in `Base` I cannot write `func`. And I dont want to make `func` a function template.

Comment: If you don't know the types, how can you be sure that they are the same, so that `dynamic_cast` succeeds?

Comment: In the snippet I included the `std::cout<<"now i deal with invalid type case"<<std::endl;` to let people know that I am aware of this possibility.

Comment: Well being aware of an impending doom is not the same as having a good strategy to deal with it, and `std::cout << whatever` certainly isn't one. Perhaps you have one, but consider this. You are in effect bypassing static typing of C++, which is one of its core strong points. Perhaps you should be using a dynamically typed language instead.

Comment: I really appreciate any kind of criticism but I find it hard to believe that it was not clear that the `std::cout` call was a simple dummy statement since this is supposed to be just a code snippet.

Anyway, I've chosen not to implement the operators in the base class.

Comment: Of course it is a dummy statement. The problem is that there isn't really a much better non-dummy alternative. You can throw an exception and abort the whole computation, but IMHO this is not really a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232738/discussion-between-orlandini-and-n-pronouns-m).